# Is it possible to use wget or curl to download documents from the FCC ECFS site?

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to use the FCC's Electronic Comment Filing System (ECFS) to bulk download filings in individual proceedings. They have an API that will return every filing in a proceeding. It returns a URL for individual documents in the format:

https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/document/10809709027819/1

However, while this works in the browser, it only downloads a placeholder HTML file saying JavaScript it required when I use wget or curl. I tried examining the page in my browser but couldn't find anything like a source URL for the actual PDF.

Is there a way to use wget or curl to get at the actual PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the request that returns the PDF using Firefox's browser tools, and trimmed down the request headers to get the minimal request that returns a PDF. This works for me:

```
% curl 'https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/documents/10809709027819/1' -H 'Referer: https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/document/10809709027819/1' | file -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  146k    0  146k    0     0   516k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  518k
/dev/stdin: PDF document, version 1.7, 9 page(s)
```

So at least for this PDF, it looks like all that's needed is to set the `Referer` header to the same URL.

Comment: You don't even need the `Referer`; Notice there's a slight difference between the URL (document**s**) and the `Referer` (document). So it works with the plural form (`documents` instead of `document`) without the Referer.

Comment: Huh, I didnt notice that all, which is why I didn't try eliminating that header. Thanks!